# Do you always have to wrap your socket.on in a io.on connection block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am new to socket.io and have realized that every server-side eventlistenrs are wrapped in a `io.on` connection block:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('event name', callback)
})
```

I am a little confused about two things:

1. do I always have to wrap my `socket.on` in this kind of blocks? Is it because the `socket` represents the individual client that raised the connection event?
2. Why should I use `socket.on` inside the block instead of `io.on` since they seem to do the same thing(like `io.on('connection', () => io.on('event name', callback))`)?

Answer (score 1):

`io.on()` means adding an event listener to the server

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('event name', callback)
})
```

`socket.on()` means adding an event listener to the client **as he connects**

You cannot add an event listener to the client if he isn't connected, yet.
So what we do, is we add an event listener to the server, that triggers, when a client connects. Once the client is connected, we add event listeners to him, that trigger, when he is sending data (for example)

Comment: This doesn't really answer whether the alternate proposed method would work.